# eventClick not fired in custom view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I use Fullcalendar.js latest.
I tried to extend the list view and I was able to define my own and see it up to the display, but the `eventClick` does not fire.
How can I fix this?

```
      { sliceEvents, createPlugin, Calendar } = FullCalendar

      CustomViewConfig = {
        classNames: [ 'fc-list table-bordered fc-list-sticky fc-listDay-view fc-view' ],
        type: 'list',
        content: (props)->
          segs = sliceEvents(props)
          html = '<div class="fc-scroller fc-scroller-liquid">' +
            '<table class="fc-list-table table-bordered">' +
            '<tbody>'
          ...

          return { html: html }
      }

      CustomViewPlugin = createPlugin({
        views: {
          customList: CustomViewConfig
        },
        eventClick: (arg)->
          console.log(arg)
      })

mainCalendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(mainCalendarEl, {
...
        plugins: [ CustomViewPlugin ],
        initialView: 'customList',
...
        eventClick: (arg)->
          console.log(arg)
...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

did you find the solution? I'm trying to do the same but I want to trigger the dateClick event. Right now, I've a dirty solution adding an "onClick" event.in jQuery but I want to improve it using the methods provided by the plugin

Comment: I gave up using custom views.
Then I used Mustache.js for rendering, and for get data `getEventById()`.

Comment: @ysakmrkm Can you share an example of how you used Mustache.js for rendering. I'm also using custom views and I'm having trouble with the eventClick?